# input type = "file" (actual file?)

Tags: html

I was curious if using input type = "file" will store the actual file that was selected? If so, how would I display that file, preferably a photo, inside of a div or span? I'm working on a project where people can sell their stuff. I'm looking for a way to display the picture that a user submits, somewhat like the way Facebook does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## How would you display that file

You would have a server recieve the form data, and then do one of the following

- Serve the posted file from the server itself.
- Upload the file to another server or cloud which serves the file.

You can then send this hosted URL to the client as an image source to show it.

You'll want to check the file to make sure it is not mallicious, and probably randomise the name to make attacking the system harder, to prevent someone from uploading a PHP shell and taking over the server.

Answer (score 0):

I have figured out a way using javascript to display the picture after it's been selected for upload. The code is as follows (Entire document).

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en" class="no-js">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">



    <script class="jsbin" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script class="jsbin" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.0/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro:400,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/reset.css"> <!-- CSS reset -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css"> <!-- Resource style -->
    <script src="js/modernizr.js"></script> <!-- Modernizr -->

<script>
function displayProduct(){
var product = document.getElementById("productTitle").value;
var productDesc = document.getElementById("productDescription").value;
var files = document.getElementById("blah").src;
    document.getElementById("showProduct").style.display = "block";
    document.getElementById("productHead").innerHTML = product;
    document.getElementById("productD").innerHTML = productDesc;
    document.getElementById("photo").innerHTML = files;
    }

     function readURL(input) {
            if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
                var reader = new FileReader();

                reader.onload = function (e) {
                    $('#blah')
                        .attr('src', e.target.result)
                        .width(150)
                        .height(200);
                };

                reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
            }
             if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
                var reader = new FileReader();

                reader.onload = function (e) {
                    $('#photo')
                        .attr('src', e.target.result)
                        .width(150)
                        .height(200);
                };

                reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
            }
        }

</script>

    <title>XXXXXXXXX dot Com</title>
</head>
<body>
<header>
<img src = "brownBag.jpg" width = "8%" style = "float: left;">
  <h3>Deal Finder dot Com</h3>
    <nav class="cd-stretchy-nav">
        <a class="cd-nav-trigger" href="#0">
            Menu
            <span aria-hidden="true"></span>
        </a>

        <ul>
            <li><a href="http://www.nephilim42.com/mySiteIndex.html"><span>The Homepage of Nephilim42 Coding</span></a></li>
            <li><a href="http://www.nephilim42.com/XXXXXX.html"><span>CSS Portfolio Project</span></a></li>
            <li><a href="http://www.nephilim42.com/XXXXXX.html"><span>Javascript Portfolio Project</span></a></li>
            <li><a href="http://www.nephilim42.com/gamedarts/gamedarts.html"><span>Play a game of Darts! Powered by Javascript</span></a></li>
            <li><a href="http://www.nephilim42.com/XXXXXX/index.html"><span>My First Business Website</span></a></li>
        </ul>

        <span aria-hidden="true" class="stretchy-nav-bg"></span>
    </nav>

</header>

<main class="cd-main-content">
<label for = "form">

        <form name = "postForm" id = "postForm" method = "POST" action = "">

            <p>What are you selling?
                <input type = "text" name = "productTitle" id = "productTitle">
            </p><br>
            <p>Please describe your product.
                <textarea name = "productDescription" id = "productDescription" cols = "50" rows = "6"></textarea>
            </p><br>
            <p>Upload Picture:
                <input type='file' onchange="readURL(this);" />
                <img id="blah" src="#" alt="your image" />
            </p>
            <input type = "button" name = "post" id = "post" value = "POST" onClick = "displayProduct()"><br>
        </form>

        <div id = "showProduct">
            <p>Product Title:
                <span id = "productHead"></span>
            </p><br>
            <p>Product Description:
                <span id = "productD"></span>
            </p><br>
            <p>Uploaded Photo:
                <span id = "photo"></span>
            </p>
        </div>


<script src="js/jquery-2.1.4.js"></script>
<script src="js/main.js"></script> <!-- Resource jQuery -->
</body>
</html>
```

Below are some attached images. Unfortunately because I have low reputation here on stackOverflow, only the link will attach. Which do work when copied and pasted into the URL search bar. These images show the steps with what happens when uploading a file. unfortunately I have ran into a problem, but I will work on fixing it. The problem is on image #2. The second chunk of javascript in the readURL function is a failed attempt to rectify that.

Image 1) Upload button clicked, selecting image
Image 2) After image is selected and posted, the value of the file is sent via innerHTML to a span. The value seems to be a super long character string rather than the image in the span. I will try to work on this and fix it, and post on this thread the solution.

1 https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Ev4b.png
  2 https://i.stack.imgur.com/L0ymG.png